# How to unpack a dict for function arguments in jinja2 template

Tags: python, dictionary, templates, jinja2, unpack

how can I unpack a dict in a jinja2 template, like in python code, to add arguments in a call.

in python:

```
mydict={'hello': 'world'}
myfunction(one=1, **mydict)
```

is the same as:

```
myfunction(one=1, hello='world')
```

Is it possible to do this in a jinja2 template?

trying this:

```
{{ set mydict={'hello': 'world' }}
{{ myfunction one=1 **mydict }}
```

gives me this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'dict'